# Why does this work? Fourier coefs. of function with min energy in window is eigenvector of window coef. matrix.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Let me begin with saying I have never got a good handle on eigenvectors and eigenvalues. My best hunch is that the eigenvectors are the 'best' basis for a linear transform along which the transform space varies the least(?).

Anyway, I am reading a paper at the moment and trying to work out how the following works. Paraphrasing from the paper:

Let $w(\theta) \in \mathbb{R}, \theta \in [-\pi,\pi)$ be a symmetric window function, and

$$p(\theta) = \sum_{n=-N}^{N} u_n e^{i n \theta}, \qquad u_{-n} = \bar{u}_n$$

be a real valued function made from the first $N$ Fourier series components, ($N$-th order trig. polynomial.) with $\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{u} = 1.$

We want to find the values of $\mathbf{u}$ that minimise the energy of $p(\theta)$ within the window $w(\theta)$. This energy functional is

$$\sum_{n'=-N}^{N}\sum_{n=-N}^{N} \bar{u}_{n'}u_n \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i (n-n') \theta} w(\theta)\,d\theta = \mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{W}\mathbf{u}$$

where $W_{n,n'} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i (n-n') \theta} w(\theta)\,d\theta$

The paper then goes on to say that the best choice for $\mathbf{u}$ is the eigenvector of $\mathbf{W}$ corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue.

**Why?**

Edit: $w(\theta)$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have eigenvalues in a very specific context. We have got an inner product space (the span of the complex exponentials $\theta\mapsto e^{n\mathbf i\theta}$ for $-N\leq n\leq N$) with the standard inner product on the basis of those exponentials (that is, in coordinate vectors $\def\u{\mathbf u}\def\v{\mathbf v}(\u,\v)=\u^H\v$). The window $w$ is in fact used to describe a second form $\def\W{\mathbf W}(\u,\v)_w=\u^H \W\v$, which is symmetric: $\W^H = \W$. Then a spectral theorem says that $\W$ is unitarily diagonalisable (that is, with an orthonormal set of eigenvectors) and real eigenvalues. In matrix terms $\def\R{\mathbf R}\def\D{\mathbf D}\W=\R^H\D\R$ where $\D$ is a real diagonal matrix and $\R$ is an unitary matrix: $\R^H\R=I$.

This means one has an eigenvector basis $\mathcal B$ that is at the same time orthonormal for the standard inner product, and orthogonal for $(,)_w$. This means that if now $\u'=\R\u$ and $\v'=\R\v$ are the new coordinates of $\u,\v$ *with respect to the eigenvector basis $\mathcal B$*, then one still has $(\u,\v)=\u^H\mathbf v=(\u')^H\v'$, but also $(\u,\v)_w=\u^H\W\v=\u^H\R^h\D\R\v=(\u')^H \D\v'$. Now it is very easy to see that if one wants to minimize $(\u')^H \D\u'$ relative to the constraint of the unit sphere $(\u')^H \u'=1$, then one should take for $\u'$ the vector with a coordinate $1$ at the position to the smallest diagonal entry of$~\D$, and $0$ elsewhere. Indeed the constraint reads $\sum_i|u_i'|^2=1$ while $(\u')^H \D\u'=\sum_i\lambda_i|u_i'|^2$ where the $\lambda_i$ are the diagonal entries of$~\D$ (which are the eigenvalues of$~\W$). One obtains $\min_i(\lambda_i)\leq \sum_i\lambda_i|u_i'|^2 \leq\max_i(\lambda_i)$ by simple estimation of each term $\min_i(\lambda_i)|u_i'|^2\leq \lambda_i|u_i'|^2 \leq\max_i(\lambda_i)|u_i'|^2$, and adding the inequalities.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Repeating back in my own words: Normal inner product is $u^Hv = u^HIv$, 'windowed' inner product is $u^HWv$. If $Ru$ is projection $u$ onto the basis of $W$, then $u^HWv = (Ru)^HI(Ru)$. Since $u^Hu=1$, using $u=$ the eigenvector (also norm 1) with the smallest eigenvalue will give the smallest value. I assume the last bit is a simple proof like triangle inequality?. Is the opposite also true: max eigenvalue = max energy? Must the coordinate vector of $w(\theta)$ be all non-zero?

Comment: @geometrikal Some corrections: it is not "projection onto the basis" (which suggest some information disappears) but "coordinate transformation to the new basis". The matrix $R$ that does this is _unitary_: $R^H R=I$, that's essential here. So computing $(Ru)^H(Ru)$ in the transformed coordinates still gives $u^H u$. On the other hand $(Ru)^HD(Ru)=u^HR^HDRu=u^HWu$ gives the " windowed inner product" (you wrote $I$ instead of $D$, maybe a typo). The last part is just about the extremes of $\sum_i\lambda_i|z_i|^2$ on the unit sphere $\sum_i|z_i|^2=1$ where $z_i$ are entries of $Ru$; it is easy.

Comment: I've modified the answer to give a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the follow up, your answer has really helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an intuitive understanding, consider first the case where $W$ is a diagonal matrix, say $W = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \end{pmatrix}$ with $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \lambda_3$.

Let $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3)^T$ with $u^T u = 1$, then $u^T W u = u_1^2 \lambda_1 + u_2^2 \lambda_2 + u_3^2 \lambda_3$.
In order to minimize this value, we need to maximize $u_1$ and minimize $u_2$ and $u_3$, therefore $u = (1,0,0)^T$ which is the eigenvector corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue.

If $W$ is not diagonal but diagonalizable, the same argument goes through:
$W = R^T \tilde W R$ for a diagonal $\tilde W$, then $u^T W u = (Ru)^T \tilde W (Ru)$.
We have to choose $Ru$ to be the eigenvector of the lowest eigenvalue of $\tilde W$, this corresponds to $u$ being the eigenvector of that eigenvalue of $W$.

The paper probably assumes that $w(\theta)$ is a symmetric function, then $W$ is a symmetric matrix (substitute $\theta\mapsto -\theta$ in the integral) and hence diagonalizable.
If $W$ wasn't, we'd get a similar result but we'd have to talk about generalized eigenspaces.

Comment: Yep $w(\theta)$ is symmetric, I have edited the question for future readers. Good explanation, I think I almost have it. Could the opposite be done - maximise using the max eigenvalue?

Comment: I think this answer should mention the essential point that $R$ can be taken to be _unitary_.